# bitwise and returns black image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

let us suppose we have following image :

[image]

i would like to apply some  bitwise and  on this image, so i just experimented with  following mask :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
image1 =cv2.imread("ML.png")
image1 =cv2.resize(image1,(400,400))
print(image1)
mask =np.zeros((400,400,3),dtype='uint8')
mask[0:50,0:120]=1
mask[70:180,130:320] =1
mask[150:240,190:390] =1
print(mask)
image1_changed =cv2.bitwise_and(image1,mask)
print(image1_changed)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(image1_changed))
plt.show()
```

actually i want to leave only head part and remove rest of them, all matrices are here :

```
[[[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]

 [[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]

 [[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]

 ...

 [[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]

 [[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]

 [[255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  ...
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]
  [255 250 245]]]
[[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
[[[1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  [1 0 1]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

how to define well  such matrix?  previous code returns black  image, please help me

Comment: bitwise operations operate on bits. your mask contains `1`, not `255`. the result is contains values `0` and `1` only. that's black and almost-black. do you understand now what you saw?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need to keep the head (brain) part and remove rest. You can create mask by selecting the points from original image and make it to 255 , Note you assigned this to 1 which won't be very clear as its black (close to 0). See below code with comment in explanation. Hope this helps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Read image
image = cv2.imread('ML.png')
#Create mask as same as image size.
mask =np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],1),dtype='uint8')

#Mask rectangle is selected as points from original image.
mask[30:240,57:168]=255

#Resize image and mask
image1 =cv2.resize(image,(400,400))
mask1 = cv2.resize(mask,(400,400))

#Do bitwise and
image1_changed =cv2.bitwise_and(image1,image1, mask=mask1)

#Save mask and masked image result.
cv2.imwrite("mask.png",mask1)
cv2.imwrite("changed.png",image1_changed)
```

output 'changed.png'
[image]